# How to disable certain words in PHPStorm autocompletion

Tags: css, phpstorm

Many times when phpstorm tries to autocomplete my css it will make very poor and annoying choices, for example when I type colo and hit enter it puts 'columns' instead of 'color'.

Is there any way to remove columns and other non used clutter from the autocompletion?

Comment: How does that `colo` selects you the `columns` instead of `color`? Screenshot please (better -- small screencast). If you would just type `col` .. then I may agree with you... In any case: if the entry in completion list is actual CSS property and not some live template entry ... then you cannot remove it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/DE_2j8uPclA

Comment: Does work OK here .. so must be my settings. 1) What's your IDE version exactly? 2) What key did you use to insert the selection (Tab, Enter, etc)? 3) You have recorded very small area. Any chance to show it wider? 4) What file type is that? Pure `.css` .. or `.less`/etc?  Or maybe it's a css/php mix (file will be processed by PHP but returned to browser as .css)?

Comment: In any case: based on screenshot it's not the actual property .. so it most likely will be either Emmet or Live Template (possibly custom one .. or you may be using not the latest IDE version). So .. 1) do you see any explanation text on the right side of the completion entry (you may need to make your completion popup wider) 2) `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates` -- see if you have any entry that will have `colo` or similar abbreviation (check `ZenCSS` group first). If so -- disable it.

Comment: HI there I am using phpstorm 8.2 ... that is probably the problem...

Comment: Could be... Try latest 10.0.3 -- it can be installed into separate folder + will store it's global config separately. You will only need to make backup of your project settings (`.idea` subfolder) if you decide to work in v8 again (project settings gets updated to newer versions once opened in newer iDE version and going back to older IDE may end up in loosing some of the project settings)